# Python Series Sum Resample

Tags: python

Given a list [5,2,4,5,1,2,4,5], how to do a *sum* resample like [pandas.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) `df.resample().sum()` without the hasle of creating a `DatetimeIndex`?

```
inp = [5,2,4,5,1,2,4,5]
out = resample(inp, 2, how='sum')

>> [7, 9, 3, 9]
```

Note: This is because `df.resample().sum()` only accept `datetime-like index`. I have spent some time googling this topic but find nothing. Sorry if there is exist a same question like this.

Edit:

A manual solution might look like this

```
import numpy as np

def resample_sum(inp, window):
    return np.sum(np.reshape(inp, (len(inp)//window, window)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
def resample(inp_list,window_size,how='sum'):
    output = []
    for i in range(0,len(inp_list),window_size):
        window = inp_list[i:i+window_size]
        if how == 'sum':
           output.append(sum(window))
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError #replace this with other how's you want
    return output
            
inp = [5,2,4,5,1,2,4,5]
out = resample(inp, 2, how='sum')
#[7, 9, 3, 9]
```

**Edit 1:** A vectorized numpy array solution which will have better performance for a huge array. The idea is to reshape the array into a 2-d array where the rows of the new array are the values that should be summed together.

```py
import numpy as np
def resample(inp_array,window_size,how='sum'):
    inp_array = np.asarray(inp_array)

    #check how many zeros need to be added to the end to make
    #   the array length a multiple of window_size 
    pad = (window_size-(inp_array.size % window_size)) % window_size
    if pad > 0:
        inp_array = np.r_[np.ndarray.flatten(inp_array),np.zeros(pad)]
    else:
        inp_array = np.ndarray.flatten(inp_array)

    #reshape so that the number of columns = window_size
    inp_windows = inp_array.reshape((inp_array.size//window_size,window_size))
    
    if how == 'sum':
       #sum across columns
       return np.sum(inp_windows,axis=1)
    else:
       raise NotImplementedError #replace this with other how's you want

inp = [5,2,4,5,1,2,4,5]
out = resample(inp, 2, how='sum')
#[7, 9, 3, 9]
```

**Edit 2:**
The closest thing to this I found in a popular library is [skimage.measure.block_reduce](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html?#block-reduce).

You can treat your data as a 1-dimensional image, pass a block size, and pass the np.sum function.

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem, but I want to see is there an optimized library to do this simple task out there.

Comment: If you are worried about performance you probably just need a vectorized solution, not necessarily a library. I'll add a vectorized numpy solution as well.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni Added a couple alternatives. Edit 1 shows a vectorized numpy solution that should work fast for very large arrays (to scratch the "optimized" issue). Edit 2 shows a popular library function I found that seems to do the same thing but for multi-dimensional images.

Comment: Thank you. Really want to test benchmark the vectorized solutions vs skimage in a *need padding case*.